# scheme- sum of values in a list of characters

Tags: list, char, sum, scheme

I'm new to Scheme and I'm trying to figure out why the following function doesn't work.. I want to sum the int values of a list of characters (so that the value of the character '1' is 1 and so on). This is what I tried to do:

```
(define (func ls sum)
(cond
  ((null? ls)(sum))
  (else(func (cdr ls)(+ sum string->number(string(car ls)))))))
```

but when I try to run it like this:

```
(func '() 0)
```

I get: "application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 0
  arguments...: [none]" error.
or:
"contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #number>
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments.:"
 when I try other inputs..

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `string->number(string(car ls))`

Comment: Have you [searched for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22application%3A+not+a+procedure%22)?  This might be a duplicate.

Comment: I have, but nothing I found with the same error helped me understand it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your function, due to parentheses. The first is the use of `(sum)`: this is interpreted as the call to a parameterless function `sum`. The second is the use of `string->number` *without* parentheses:

```
(+ sum string->number(string(car ls)))
```

This is interpreted as calling the function `+` with three arguments: `sum`, `string->number` (which is a function and not a number), and `(string(car ls))` (which is a string and not a number).

Here is the correct function:

```
(define (func ls sum)
  (cond
    ((null? ls) sum)
    (else (func (cdr ls) (+ sum (string->number (string (car ls))))))))
```

You should always remember that a function call in Scheme is written as a *form*:

```
(function arg1 arg2 ... argn)
```